# How doesn't UILabel implementation intrinsicContentSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As we known, UILabel has intrinsicContentSize, my puzzle is when we pin a label to it's superview with leading and trailing offset 10 for example, and set the numberOfLines to 0, assume the superview is a viewcontroller's view that has a width 320, and how label knows it's width is 300.
Another, when there are mutiple constraint that the label is compressed, and how the label know it's compressed and recalculate it's size?

Comment: calculate the size on the basis of uiscreen size

Answer (score 3):

The intrinsicContentSize is independent of any context, including any constraint applied to the label. This is, actually, the meaning of *intrinsic*.

So when you ask for the intrinsicContentSize of a label, it *does not know* that its width is gonna be 300, and indeed it returns any width that fits its content. Go on, check it: ask the the intrinsicContentSize of a label which contains "foo", or "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae sapien nec elit tongue incident." You won't get the same result.

Know you may wonder: if the intrinsicContentSize is (52,21) or (633,21), why on earth does it end at (300, 21)?

Well the answer is simple: the intrinsicContentSize generates implicit constraints whose priorities are controlled by the contentHuggingPriority and contentCompressionResistancePriority of the label. Those are generally less than 1000. On the opposite, the priority of the leading and trailing offsets are 1000, the maximum. So the offset constraints win in the final layout, and the label ends with a 300 width.

Now try to set contentHuggingPriority and contentCompressionResistancePriority to 1000: you will see a *conflict*. Do you see why?

Comment: THX. I seems that the UILabel use a property `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to calculate the height of it. The value default is 0, and I'm wondering how this value is set to 300 in the case above.

Comment: Now that's a different question. The preferredMaxLayoutWidth is indeed used by intrinsicContentSize: it tells the label when it should wrap lines. I'm not sure when it has been set to 300, but I suspect the storyboard, or the xib file which contains the UILabel.

Comment: The preferredMaxLayoutWidth is the topmost item in the Size inspector of your label.